# Unable to render vector points on mapbox GL

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, mapbox-gl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Display a map</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2x5IiwiYSI6IjdiYzFmZmY5NTExOTQ0MTExMGVhZDBkZTIwMmRlYjJhIn0.hOz2brurCBMGWGU5EI-waQ';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
    center: [-3.69964599609375, 40.417874374140474], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 13 // starting zoom
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'population',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': {
                    "type": "vector",
                    "tiles": ["http://localhost:4000/windwalker_test/tiles/test_table/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"]

        },
        'source-layer': 'defaultLayer',
        'paint': {
            'circle-color': 'red'
        }
    });
});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am hosting a node-mapnik server on http://localhost:4000 that has point data. A sample vector pbf from the server is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3f5pnt5rjcfxxw/test_table_13_4011_3088.pbf?dl=0

Mapnik rendering this as a raster is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7Z6.png

Reading the protobuf file using https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js I get the following:

```
VectorTile {
    layers: {
        defaultLayer: VectorTileLayer {
            version: 2,
            name: 'defaultLayer',
            extent: 4096,
            length: 5,
            _pbf: {
                buf: < Buffer 1 a cc 03 78 02 0 a 0 c 64 65 66 61 75 6 c 74 4 c 61 79 65 72 28 80 20 1 a 07 61 64 64 72 65 73 73 22 2 a 0 a 28 43 61 6 c 6 c 65 20 64 65 20 50 c3 a9 72 65 7 a... > ,
                pos: 463,
                type: 2,
                length: 463
            },
            _keys: ['address', 'cartodb_id', 'name'],
            _values: ['Calle de Pérez Galdós 9, Madrid, Spain',
                1,
                'Hawai',
                'Calle de la Palma 72, Madrid, Spain',
                2,
                'El Estocolmo',
                'Plaza Conde de Toreno 2, Madrid, Spain',
                3,
                'El Rey del Tallarín',
                'Manuel Fernández y González 8, Madrid, Spain',
                4,
                'El Lacón',
                'Calle Divino Pastor 12, Madrid, Spain',
                5,
                'El Pico'
            ],
            _features: [107, 187, 278, 366, 443]
        }
    }
}
```

Which the information seems correct. Yet when I view the map where the points are located I don't see them. What am I missing?

Ive tried `type: line` and `type: fill` and using `line-color` and `fill-color`. I also played around with `circle-radius` with no luck

The mapnik server will produce a png or a pbf if you change the extention so I've confirmed that when using type:raster and specifying png that it correctly renders the raster so there must be something I am not doing right

Comment: Wasn't clear from your description, but did you try `type: 'circle'` with `fill-color: 'red'`?

Comment: I didn't, just tried it and I get an error `layers.population.paint.fill-color: unknown property "fill-color"` I think fill-color isn't valid for `type: 'circle'` only valid with `type: 'fill'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer, turns out I dynamically set the layer Id right before it gets output from node.

Requesting a close on this SO as it cannot help anyone in the future